# Running a very simple Weld SE project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-weld

I've been using Seam 2 (also started looking into Java EE 6) in my web apps and a couple of days ago I found out that Seam's CDI can be leveraged in an SE application with Weld. According to Weld's Documentation page for [Weld SE](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#weld-se) the setup is trivial. So I tried to setup an Eclipse project with a single class HelloWeld, weld-se.jar and the log4j jars.

```
@Singleton
public class HelloWeld
{
    public void printHello(@Observes ContainerInitialized event, @Parameters List<String> parameters)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Weld!");
    }
}
```

I created a new Java Application Run Configuration and indicated `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain` as the main class. When I ran the project I found out, without any surprise what-so-ever, that HelloWeld was never called. All I got was a few log entries as an indication that Weld booted correctly:

```
11:54:39,397 INFO  [weld.Version] WELD-000900 1.0.1 (Final)
11:54:39,428 INFO  [weld.Bootstrap] WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
11:54:39,944 WARN  [model.InterceptionTypeRegistry] Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
11:54:39,944 WARN  [model.InterceptionTypeRegistry] Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make it a bean archive.  Add an empty META-INF/beans.xml to your classpath.